# Pandas reading Date as String instead of datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I'am writing a program to load the excel file into database but while using pandas to load the data its giving error as it is reading date as string , though the same is working fine with openpyxl

Code using Pandas

```
    try:
        Conf=LoadConfig.loadConfig()
        cursor, connection =Util.getConnection(Conf['SRC'])
        data = data.applymap(lambda s: removeSpecialCharacters(s))
        columNameList=[col for col in data.columns]
        DataListInp=data.to_dict('records')

        query='TRUNCATE TABLE '+name
        cursor.execute(query)

        query='insert into '+name+'('
        columnstring=",".join(str(x) for x in columNameList)
        paramString=",".join(':'+str(x) for x in columNameList)

        finalquery=query+columnstring+') values( '+paramString+')'
        cursor.prepare(finalquery)
        cursor.executemany(None, DataListInp)
        connection.commit()
    except Exception as  e:
        print(e)
        traceback.print_exc()
    finally:
        if cursor is not None:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()

def loadExcel(filename,sheets):
    sheetList=sheets.split(',')
    sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheetList,keep_default_na=False)
    for name, data in sheets_dict.items():
        print(name,'Sheet Loading Start')
        loadSheets(data,name)
        print(name,'Sheet Loading Finished')
```

Code Using OpenPyxl:

```
    try:
        cursor, connection =Util.getConnection(Conf['SRC'])
        SheetData=tuple(ws.values)
        columNameList=list(SheetData[0])
        DataListInp=list(SheetData[1:])
        #DataList = [tuple(map(lambda i: str.replace(str(i),'\xa0',"") if isinstance(i, str) else i, tup)) for tup in DataListInp]
        DataList = [tuple(map(lambda i: str.replace(str.replace(str.replace(str(i),'_x000D_'," "),'\xa0'," "),'\n'," ") if isinstance(i, str) else i, tup)) for tup in DataListInp]
        paramDictionary=[dict(zip(columNameList,row)) for row in DataList]
        query='insert into '+ws.title+'('
        columnstring=",".join(str(x) for x in columNameList)
        paramString=",".join(':'+str(x) for x in columNameList)
        finalquery=query+columnstring+') values( '+paramString+')'
        cursor.prepare(finalquery)
        cursor.executemany(None, paramDictionary)
        connection.commit()
    except Exception as  e:
        print(e)
        traceback.print_exc()
    finally:
        if cursor is not None:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
        if len(sys.argv) != 3:
            logging.debug("No of Parameter should be 2 . 1= file_name, 2= sheets")
            exit()
        i_runParams=sys.argv
        file_name=i_runParams[1]
        sheets=i_runParams[2]
        print(file_name)
        print(sheets)
        wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name,data_only=True)
        sheetList=sheets.split(',')
        print(sheetList)
        for sheet in sheetList:
            ws=wb[sheet]
            print(ws.title,' Sheet Loading Start')
            loadSheets(ws)
            print(ws.title,'Sheet Loading Finished')
```

Problem is pandas is reading the date field in excel as below 
 'CREATE_DATE': '2019-04-04 00:00:00', 'UPDATE_DATE': '2019-04-04 00:00:00',

though OpenPyxl is reading as

'CREATE_DATE': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 4, 0, 0), 'UPDATE_DATE': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 4, 0, 0)

How can we get the same result from pandas ? cannot change the datatype of column as we dont know which column will be date it needs to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a try statement which will attempt to convert the fields as they're loaded to datetime and continue if they fail?

```
import pandas as pd

Date = '01-02-2019'
NotDate = 'Not Date'
for i in [Date, NotDate]:
    try:

        if pd.to_datetime(i):
            print(i + ' is a date')

    except:
        print(i + ' is not a date')
```

Output:

```
01-02-2019 is a date
Not Date is not a date
```

Comment: Thanks Krewsayder, but this will only complicate the process ,its better to use openpyxl in that case. can  parse_dates , date_parser help for this ? i tried using date_parser by using lamda to convert string to date but that also didn't worked. may be i'm missing something ?